# I want to create the 'times table (2x2 = 4)' table using the GridView in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, gridview, datarow

1. I want to create a 9x9 GridView, list the numbers 1 through 9 in columns and rows, and then put the values ​​into an array.
   I want to create it using for and Array, but I do not know what to do.
2. The current state is that the value is displayed below the column and all the values ​​appear only on one row.

I want to complete one program and help.

aspx.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
<Columns></Columns>
```

aspx.cs.

```
public partial class GridEX : System.Web.UI.Page{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        int i = 1;
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            for (; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(i + "단");
            }

            for (int k = 1; k <= 9; k++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int m = 1; m <= 9; m++)
                { dr[m] = i; }

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                dt.Rows.Add(i * k);
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
}
```

What I want image:

[image]

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. A Gridview is designed to work with a datasource of some description. The way you want to do it is inefficient, you will have nested loops to create the dataset, then the overhead of binding that dataset. You would be better off with a [Table Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bewx260.aspx). Create the rows and cells in your loops and skip the binding step. If you are interested in this approach I can create an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Factor1");
dt.Columns.Add("Factor2");
dt.Columns.Add("Result");

for(int i=2; i<=9; i++)
{
  for (int j=1; j<=10; j++)
  {
    dt.Rows.Add(i, j, i*j);
  }
}

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have your reasons for wanting to use a Gridview here, but in my opinion, it is not the right way to achieve your goal. DataBinding is a useful tool but it does come with processing overhead, at the very least it is another iteration.

You can use a DataTable to achieve the same thing without the binding overhead.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Table ID="MulitiplicationTable" runat="server"></asp:Table>
```

**C#**

```
for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
{
    TableRow newRow = new TableRow();
    MulitiplicationTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

    for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++)
    {
        TableCell newCell = new TableCell();
        newRow.Cells.Add(newCell);
        //Empty cell for our first cell...                    
        if ((row + column) == 0)
        {
            newCell.Text = "&nbsp;";
        }
        //Our Column and row headers are also
        //Special Cases
        else if(row == 0)
        {
            newCell.Text = column.ToString();
            newCell.CssClass = "columnHead";
        }
        else if(column == 0)
        {
            newCell.Text = row.ToString();
            newCell.CssClass = "rowHead";
        }
        //Now do the math
        else
        {
            newCell.Text = (row * column).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable table9x9 = new DataTable();
        if (table9x9.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    table9x9.Columns.Add(" ");
                else
                    table9x9.Columns.Add(i+"");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 1; row <= 9; row++)
        {
            DataRow dr = table9x9.NewRow();
            for (int column = 0; column <= 9; column++)
            {
                if (column == 0)
                    dr[" "] = row;
                else
                    dr[column + ""] = row * column;
            }
            table9x9.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        GridView2.DataSource = table9x9;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

### Output:

[image]